# Check if 2 functions are linearly independent

Tags: trigonometry, wronskian

I have 2 functions:

$$f_1(x) = \cos(4x)$$ $$ f_2(x) = \cos(6x)$$
I used Wronskian and got

$W(x) = -6\cos(4x)\sin(6x)+4\sin(4x)\cos(6x)$

> Now how can I tell if $W(x)$ equals $0$ (or not) with trigonometric identities?

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Try $x=\frac\pi4$

Comment: You can check that $W(k\frac{\pi}{2})=0$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ but for other values it is non zero.

Comment: It suffices to check that $W(x_0) \neq 0$ for one value of $x_0$ to conclude linear independence. Shoot away your $x_0$'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$-6\cos(4x)\sin(6x) +4\sin(4x)\cos(6x) =0 \\ \implies 4\left(\sin(4x)\cos(6x) -\sin(6x)\cos(4x)\right) =2\cos(4x)\sin(6x) \\ \implies -4\sin(2x)=\sin(10x)+\sin(2x) \\ \implies \sin(10x) =-5\sin(2x)$$ This is not true for every $x$, for example take $x=\frac{\pi}{10}$.